# How to make Ruby's N ends look better?

Tags: ruby, syntax, refactoring, coding-style

As I write some scripts, I usually reach a point where my code looks like this :

```
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know about you, but this look very ugly to me. Can something be done about this?

Comment: This isn't exclusive to Ruby.  Staircase code has been around forever.

Comment: Python is nice for this since it only stairs outwards, not back in again.  I know it isn't an option, but that was one of the design goals of python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't nest your code so much? Refactor to use more methods? Use blocks passed to other routines instead?

Generally speaking, deep nesting is an indicator that a method is getting too complex and should be broken up. It can help for implicit structural documentation too, by naming the inner compound statements according to their refactored methods.

Answer (score 5):

The advice to break up into smaller pieces is good. But if you need a lot of nested blocks like that, you can label the `end` keywords with comments.

```
    end # End conditional statement
  end # End method declaration
end # End class declaration
```

Still ugly, but at least clearer.

The other options previously mentioned are preferable.

Answer (score 4):

If those inner blocks do something easy to name (and maybe reusable?), why not refactor them into small separate functions ? Then you'd end up with much shorter sequences of end's.

Otherwise another approach is using Python :-)

Comment: I was sure someone would suggest Python :)

Comment: I actually had in mind both Python and Potion [http://github.com/why/potion/tree/master] - but the latter is a bit more of experimental flavour :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use small, testable functions. Not only are your functions and more importantly logic easy to test, but your code becomes way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen nested "{ }" blocks and 4-space soft tabs and:

> end;end;end;end

I suppose this saves vertical space, but I don't recommend, The above comments on avoiding deep nesting and commenting your block-ending lines are the valid approaches.  Maybe deep nesting is to avoid method call overhead for things that need speeding up, but readability almost always trumps that kind of "optimization"

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to compile your own Ruby, you could use [ennnnnnnd](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ku-ma-me/20110718/p1) style syntax (link is to RubyKaigi talk). Unfortunately for you, this has been suggested and [rejected](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5054) by Ruby core.

Comment: +1 for the link, even though I'm still happy that this got rejected.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: I think it's good to have both the curiosity to see if you can do something, and the wisdom to realize you probably shouldn't.